# Sonata: How to warn users to fill out a non-mandatory field?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I have an application based on Sonata Admin Bundle and Symfony 3.3.

In this application, I have an ImagePair entity that contains three fields: two Image entities and a string. Here is what my relevant code looks like right now:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('name')
        ->add(
            'imageOne',
            'sonata_type_model',
            array('expanded' => false, 'by_reference' => true, 'multiple' => false, 'required' => true),
            array(
                'link_parameters' => array(
                'context' => 'default',
                'provider' => 'sonata.media.provider.image')
            )
        )
        ->add(
            'imageTwo',
            'sonata_type_model',
            array('expanded' => false, 'by_reference' => true, 'multiple' => false, 'required' => true),
            array(
                'link_parameters' => array(
                'context' => 'default',
                'provider' => 'sonata.media.provider.image')
            )
        )
    ;
}
```

When any of the three fields gets filled out, I want to warn the user about any remaining unfilled fields **without making those fields mandatory**.

Is there a standardized way to do this type of thing with Sonata? If not, what would I need to do in order to inject arbitrary JavaScript into my admin screen?

Comment: I think that you have to inject arbitrary Javascript.

Comment: Thanks. I am now attempting to do that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49365143/failed-to-create-object-when-using-parentconfigure-in-an-admin-class